# writing simple plugin in ArchivesSpace

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am writing a healthcheck plugin for our instance of archivesspace in the form of archivespace plugin. It is a Jruby application and the instruction for the plugins are similar to Ruby on Rails. Seems simple enough on rails application but when I followed the plugin documentations but it is still not working, can someone point me in the right direction, I basically just need to have archivespace Url :/plugins/healthcheck/ to hit the archivespace interface url, if it responds 200 response then have the page indicate success message in html. Below are code snips, any help is appreciated thanks!

```
-plugins
    -healthcheck
        -backend
            -healthcheck. rb
       -frontend
             -controller
                - healthcheck_controller.rb
```

healthcheck.rb

```
class ArchivesSpaceService < Sinatra::Base

  Endpoint.get('/healthcheck')
  .returns([200, "{'reply', 'status:ok'}"]) \

end
```

healthcheck_controller.rb

```
require 'net/http'
require 'socket'
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def healthcheck

    hostname = "status of server " + Socket.gethostname
    uri = 'http://example.com/index.html'
    status_message = "System OK"
    datetime = Time.now
  begin
    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(uri))
    status_code = res.code.to_i
    if status_code > 399
       status_code = 424
       status_message = "One or more services are currently impacted"
       img = "/img/fail.png"
    else
       img = "/img/pass.png"
    end

    render text: "<h>#{hostname} #{status_code} </h>ArchivesSpace Ok?:<br><img src='#{img}'> #{uri}<br><br>status:ok<br>" , status: status_code

  end
end
end
```